# XNA Game Studio 4.0 Collision problems i have no idea why my script is not working

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

ok so im making a 2d game im also new ill copy/paste my whole Game.cs script there are no other classed in my project except Program.cs

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;



    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }


    bool hasJumped = true;


    Vector2 velocity;
    Texture2D player;
    Texture2D ground1;



    Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(30, 30);
    Vector2 ground1p1 = new Vector2(0,430);
    Vector2 ground1p2 = new Vector2(200,430);
    Vector2 ground1p3 = new Vector2(0, 310);
    Vector2 ground1p4 = new Vector2(200, 310);


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        player = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Player");
        ground1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Ground1");

    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState newState = Keyboard.GetState();







        if ((playerPosition.Y > 0) && (playerPosition.Y < graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height-player.Height))
        {

            playerPosition += velocity;

        }


        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)&&playerPosition.X <=(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width-player.Width))
        {

                velocity.X = 3f;

        }





        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && (playerPosition.X >= 0))
        {

                velocity.X = -3f;

        }
        else velocity.X = 0f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)&& hasJumped==false)
        {
            playerPosition.Y -= 10f;
            velocity.Y = -4f;
            hasJumped = true;
        }
        if (hasJumped==true)
        {
            velocity.Y += 0.10f;
        }
        if (DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(playerPosition,ground1p1,player,ground1) == true)
        {
            hasJumped = false;
            velocity.Y = 0f;
        }
        if (DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(playerPosition, ground1p2, player, ground1) == true)
        {
            hasJumped = false;
            velocity.Y = 0f;
        }



        if (hasJumped == false)
        {
            velocity.Y = 0f;
        }


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);


        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.Draw(ground1,ground1p1 , Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(ground1, ground1p2, Color.White);

        spriteBatch.Draw(ground1, ground1p4, Color.White);


        spriteBatch.Draw(player, playerPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

 public Boolean DetectPlayerAndGround1Collision2(Vector2 playerPositionM,Vector2 groundPositionM,Texture2D playerM,Texture2D groundM)
    {

        if (playerPositionM.Y <= groundPositionM.Y + groundM.Height && playerPositionM.Y > groundPositionM.Y)
        {   
            if (playerPositionM.X < groundPositionM.X && (playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width > groundPositionM.X)) { return true; }
            else if (playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width > groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && (playerPositionM.X < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && playerPositionM.X > groundPositionM.X)) { return true; }
            else if ((playerPositionM.X > groundPositionM.X && playerPositionM.X < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width) && (playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width < groundPositionM.X + groundM.Width && playerPositionM.X + playerM.Width > groundPositionM.X)) { return true; }
        }
    }






}
```

can someone tell me why im falling throught my "ground1" sprite when im at its edge ?i have no freaking idea how im wrong in my script my last hope is to ask someone better skilled than me or maybe im blind and i cant see something stupid thanks

Comment: try switching 'playerPositionM.Y <= groundPositionM.Y + groundM.Height' for 'playerPositionM.Y >= groundPositionM.Y + groundM.Height' also it seems that the player's 'bottom' must be entirly enclosed by the platform it is standing on. if the right edge of the player's 'bottom' is over the right boundary of the platform, it is going to return false.

Comment: check out again my new Boolean function i edit it to my new script and still same problem...

Comment: is it the left, the right, or both edges the 'player' is falling off of? As I mentioned before it would appear from the way you are checking for a true condition there, that your player sprite needs to be completely within the boundaries of the 'ground' sprite. That is to say the bottom of the player sprite can't be hanging at all over the edge or it is going to return false.

Comment: from both edges its falling

Comment: oh true i got your logic about the "completely within the boundaries of the ground sprite "  but how am i suppose to fix it

Comment: maybe i have to add some pixels from the right edge X cordinate and     "-" some pixels from left edge X cordinate

Comment: well it would be a lot easier to do a slightly more complicated check. I will post an answer, but I am only going to address bottom collision with the 'ground'.

Comment: No problem. Collision is a serious topic. Most people end up writing entire engines for it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to detect collision of square A with Square B you have a lot of points to pay attention to.

Taking the simplistic example of a system of physics where box A can go up and must come down, and we are attempting to check for collision of the bottom of box A with box B, then you need to check two points of A and B before you can determine a collision.

I am going to define the two points as A.O (A Origin bottom left corner) and A.E (A extended bottom right corner). The same two points for the 'ground' exist as well.

While in motion unless box A is moving very slowly, then it is possible that you could end up within the boundaries of box B vertically as you fall. So first you need to see if the bottom of box A is in contact or passing through the top of Box B:

```
A.O.Y <= B.E.Y && A.O.Y > B.O.Y
```

Now if that comes back false then we are still falling, if it comes back true we are either on top of or inside of B.

Now that you know you are at the right height or inside the platform, you can start to check if A is over top of B:

Hanging on left edge, or somewhere in the middle, but not over the right side:

```
A.O.X < B.O.X && (A.E.X < B.E.X && A.E.X > B.O.X)
```

Hanging on the right edge, or somewhere in the middle, but not over the left side:

```
A.E.X > B.E.X && (A.O.X < B.E.X && A.O.X > B.O.X)
```

Somewhere in the middle:

```
(A.O.X > B.O.X && A.O.X < B.E.X) && (A.E.X < B.E.X && A.E.X > B.O.X)
```

if one of these conditions is true the other two are false so to put it all together you check for all three:

```
    EDIT:

flag = false

        If A.O.Y <= B.E.Y && A.O.Y > B.O.Y THEN
            If A.O.X < B.O.X && (A.E.X < B.E.X && A.E.X > B.O.X) THEN
                set flag to true
            ELSE IF A.E.X > B.E.X && (A.O.X < B.E.X && A.O.X > B.O.X) THEN
                set flag to true
            ELSE IF (A.O.X > B.O.X && A.O.X < B.E.X) && (A.E.X < B.E.X && A.E.X > B.O.X) THEN
                set flag to true

return flag
```

So reading the above we are checking first if you are on the platform vertically. Then we check in order, Hanging over left edge? Hanging over right edge? In the bounds? if any of the three are true we send it back otherwise we return false.

I hope that is helpful.

Comment: rly helpful now i see why my brain is wrong with these things but ill need some time to rethink this above to understand on 100% thanks a lot

Comment: Not a problem. Best of luck.

Comment: ok i got your code just before i test him i got a error see my edited script about Boolean Function again please something is wrong
Error : not all code paths return a value

Comment: I don't see the change to the script. If you are getting that error it means that  you have no default return value. That is to say all paths into the function do not lead out. Maybe you forgot to close your initial if statement with an else? I will edit my answer to reflect a more function like attitude.

Comment: Now I see it. I also posted a response to your question about it. You must make sure that a function always returns a value. Be sure that even if all your other conditions fail it returns false.

Comment: ok got my problem but still i have one question:
in my sample A.O.Y = playerPositionM.Y and A.E = playerPositionM.Y + playerM.Height ..... same as B.O.Y and B.E.Y and X coordinates right ?

Comment: you got it friend. The origin and the extended origin are equivalent to the bottom left corner of the sprite and the bottom right/top left corner of the sprite A.K.A bottom left + width or bottom left + height